# Can't connect to Firebase Realtime Database NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-crawler

When I try to run the below code, the following error shows up in the console:

node mcve.js
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /sitesToVisit/-Kr6oOddLtLUcpUpha7m failed: permission_denied
(node:12540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "authDomain",
    databaseURL: "databaseURL",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var database = firebase.database();
    var sitesToVisitRef = firebase.database().ref("sitesToVisit");
    var newSiteToVisitRef = sitesToVisitRef.push();
    newSiteToVisitRef.set({
      url: 'url',
      baseUrl: 'urlBase'
    });
```

Update: I tried creating a new file in a new folder, that wasn't in a public NPM package. This worked when I did a simple:

```
firebase.database().ref('usersecond').set({
    username: "ben",
    email: "hi",
    profile_picture : "imageUrl"
  });
```

After initializing the database. However, when I added the rest of my code, this set didn't affect the database; it didn't throw an error, but the data just didn't show up in the database. Could this be because I am using the NPM Request Module?

Comment: Sorry, but there's way too much code here and too little detail on the actual error. Stack Overflow is not a good interactive debugger. To get the best help, reproduce your problem in isolation and share that so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Good point. Is this better? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to write `/sitesToVisit/-Kr6oOddLtLUcpUpha7m`. If this code is running on a trusted environment (e.g. a device/server you control, or Cloud Functions), I'd consider using the Firebase Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup. This will run with administrative privilege.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have permission to write `/sitesToVisit/-Kr6oOddLtLUcpUpha7m`.

If this code is running on a **trusted environment** (e.g. a device/server you control, or Cloud Functions), I'd consider using the Firebase Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup. This will make the code run with administrative privilege, bypassing security rules.

Comment: The data from this doesn't show up either. I have used the Firebase Database in the past, both off of Github Pages and a NodeJS server(which I am using now) but for some reason it's not working now.

Comment: the admin doesn't work either for me. Does my edit to the question give any more information? For example, could it be that I'm using the NPM Request Module, and perhaps that's interfering with it somehow...? Thanks so much!